# How can I make my mods appear under the 'Mods' box?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have tried adding the mods folder to the resource packs part but it didn't work. I don't know what to do, it just won't show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your search bar (of your computer) and write `℅appdata℅` then look for a folder called `.minecraft` and then go into that folder and look for a folder called `mods`.

If you don't have a folder that is called `mods` just create one, take the Java file of the mode, and put it in the `mods` folder. Make sure you are using the right version and forge.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure you have [Forge installed](http://files.minecraftforge.net/). Choose your Minecraft version and then "Installer" or "Installer-win", download it and then run it. After you've installed Forge, (re)open the Minecraft launcher. A new profile named "Forge" should be automatically created. Select it, then press play. After Minecraft has started up, you can install mods on Windows by moving them to `%appdata%\.minecraft\mods`. Restart Minecraft and your mods should work. Just make sure they are matching the version of Forge you're using.